# Partial view does not render on dropdown postback

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using Ajax form to post back my form to render partial view in MVC. Following is a code for your reference:

**Java Script to raise dorpdown event:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ReviewPeriodID").change(function () {

        var f = $("#Form1");
        var action = f.attr("action");
        var serializedForm = f.serialize();
        $.post(action, serializedForm,
            function () 
            { 
                alert("Finished! Can do something here!") 
            });
    });

});
```

The above code executes perfectly and calls specific action on postback.

**Controller Action (Postback):**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Welcome(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        String userName = this.GetUserName();

        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = GetHomeViewModel(userName, null);
        Review review = this.OPService
                            .GetReviewDetails(model.ID, model.Employee.ID);
        homeViewModel.Review = review;

        return View(homeViewModel);
    }
```

Following is a View:

**View Code (Everything is under Ajax Form):**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Welcome", "Home", new AjaxOptions 
  { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "evaDetails" }, 
  new { id = "Form1" }))

{

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employee.ID);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employee.FirstName);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employee.LastName);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MinimumManagerCount);


<table class="tablestyle">
    <tr>
        <td class="highlightTD" colspan="2">
                      Step 1. Please select a review period</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumnTD" style="width:30%;" >Review Period</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReviewPeriodID, Model.ReviewPeriods, 
                 "-- Select Review Period --")</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<div id="evaDetails">
@{
    if (Model.Review != null)
    {
        <table class="tablestyle">
            <tr>
                <td class="highlightTD">Reviews</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.Partial("_Evaluations", Model.Review)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
</div>
}
```

Everything executes perfectly but it does not display content on browser. Can any one please help me out to identify what is wrong i am doing here?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I can see:

1. You're returning a regular View, not a Partial.
2. You're not doing anything with the result of the action in the $.post callback.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I am returning a regular view which contains a object which i am passing it to partial view:'@Html.Partial("_Evaluations", Model.Review)' is it a right approach?

Comment: @Anil - no, i dont think so. Then again, i'm not really sure what your trying to achieve, or my answer would have been more comprehensive, rather than just simple observations.

Comment: I am creating a view, which will display ondemand values to user e.g. I have two dropdowns on top of view i.e. State details and City details. On selection of either of Dropdown value i will display information to user. if user selects State then different set of information and user selects city then different set of information. Because of different type of information i had created two seperate views and was loading them on dropdown change. Please let me know in case you require more details. Appreciate your efforts to resolve my query (i am bit new to MVC)

Comment: @Anil - no probs. If all your wanting is a list of states/cities loaded asyncronously, no point in even using a partial - just return a `JsonResult` from the Controller (which is a list of cities/states), then iterate through the JSON with jQuery and bind to the dropdown.